# Grid from left to right

Tags: python, pygame

I am having troubles putting a grid of images starting from the top right corner. I am trying to do the Python Crash Course Sideway shooter project, so I tried creating a grid from the top right corner.

I can create one column in the top right corner, but when I try to write a code to create multiple columns going towards the left side of the screen, it fails to work, and no images are created at all. This is the code I have for this:

```
    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of aliens."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size

        current_x, current_y = alien_width, alien_height
        while current_x > (3 * alien_width):
            while current_y < (self.settings.height - alien_height):
                new_alien = Alien(self)
                new_alien.y = current_y
                new_alien.rect.y = current_y
                self.aliens.add(new_alien)
                current_y += 2 * alien_height
            
            current_y = alien_height
            current_x -= 3 * alien_width
```

If I only have this part of the code, the one column works fine:

```
    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of aliens."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size

        current_x, current_y = alien_width, alien_height
        while current_y < (self.settings.height - alien_height):
                new_alien = Alien(self)
                new_alien.y = current_y
                new_alien.rect.y = current_y
                self.aliens.add(new_alien)
                current_y += 2 * alien_height
```

Would anyone have an idea where it is going sideways?

I have tried the above code, and I expect to have multiple columns of aliens filling the screen from right to left.

Comment: If you want to draw the aliens from right to left, your initial value for current_x should be close to the screen's width.

Answer (score 0):

`current_x` starts at `alien_width`. So you need to step the `current_x` coordinate from left to right. And you have to `current_x` to `new_alien.x` and `new_alien.rect.x`:

```py
alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size

# from left to right
while current_x < self.settings.width - alien_width:
    
    # from top to bottom
    while current_y < self.settings.height - alien_height:

        # create new alien at current_x, current_y 
        new_alien = Alien(self)
        new_alien.rect.topleft = current_x, current_y
        new_alien.x, new_alien.y = new_alien.rect.topleft
            
        # step current_y 
        current_y += 2 * alien_height

    # reset current_y       
    current_y = alien_height
    # step current_x
    current_x += 2 * alien_width
```